# Difficulty understanding the logic

Tags: java

```
 for (int k=0;k<lngth;k++)
                {
                    if (Character.toString(line.charAt(k)).equals(gss))
                    {
                        upd=upd.substring(0,k)+" "+gss+" "+upd.substring(k+1);
                        c++; 
                    }
                }
```

In the above code, 'gss' is a letter inputted from the user, 'line' is the word say EMOTION, 'lngth' is the length of line and 'upd' stores the updated string if the letter entered matches with any of the letters of 'line' Following is a part of the output. And I cannot understand the mistake.

Please if you can find the mistake.

Thanks in advance!!

---

Enter a letter to guess the word

e

E  _ _ _ _ _ _

Enter a letter to guess the word

o

E O  O _ _ _ _ _ _

Enter a letter to guess the word

m

M  O  O _ _ _ _ _ _

Enter a letter to guess the word

n

M  O N  O _ _ _ _ _ _

Enter a letter to guess the word

Comment: Please review the SO page, [How do I ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to better your question and in return better the ability for others to respond.

Comment: @NickBell I know this is not at all a good question, but the problem is of such a kind, I couldn't find a better way of asking. If the question is not clear please ask which part of it is not clear. But I am really sorry I cannot do it better.

Comment: @ShinjineeMaiti Edit your title to summarize the core issue of your question. A generic title with no content is unhelpful and rude.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like your code assumes that the length of the `upd` String is the same as the `line` String. However, once you assign a new `String` to `upd`, you increase its length by 2 (due to the added spaces), which means the indices of `line` String no longer match the indices of `upd` String.

Try removing the added spaces and see if it solves your problem :

```
 for (int k=0;k<lngth;k++)
 {
     if (Character.toString(line.charAt(k)).equals(gss))
     {
         upd=upd.substring(0,k)+gss+upd.substring(k+1);
         c++; 
     }
 }
```